# How do we solve Shamir(2,3) sharing scheme where arithmetic is modulo 13?

Tags: cryptanalysis, secret-sharing

I am trying to get secret S and I have 3 values (2,2)(6,3)(4,9) and know that we are working modulo is 13.

I tried using Lagrange basis polynomials and got 8 but I am not sure if that is right and also I cannot find way to derive the equation of the line in form of ax+by= c (mod 13).

Comment: 8 is correct...

Comment: I cannot find way to derive the equation of the line in form of ax+by= c mod 13.

Comment: The error is, that it should be (expressed as equation) $ax+b=y$. The second values are the results of the polynomial, not an input variable of the polynomial, that factor b in front of y looks quite wrong. Also, your equation has one variable too much. But if this was a (3,3) scheme, the equation would be $ax^2+bx+c=y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose two points. (for example (2,2) and (6,3)). Then you can compute the [Lagrange interpolation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) as below:

$f(x)=2.(\dfrac{x-6}{2-6})+3.(\dfrac{x-2}{6-2})=-(\dfrac{2x-12}{4})+(\dfrac{3x-6}{4})$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =(\dfrac{x+6}{4})=(\dfrac{x}{4})+(\dfrac{6}{4})\ mod(13)=10x+60\ mod(13)=10x+8$

Because $4^{-1}=10 \ mod(13)$.

Comment: Latex has `\mod` `\bmod` and `\pmod{}`. Also `\cdot` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

The form of equation you expect is not usually applied to Shamir's Sharing Scheme. Instead the equation is usually [represented as polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing): 
$$f\left(x\right)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots+a_{k-1}x^{k-1}\,\! \mod p,$$
where $k$ is number of pieces needed to restore the secret; $a_i$ are random coefficients (modulo p) and $p$ is 13 (in your case).

According to this your "equation of the line" (after recovering it with [Lagrange interpolation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)) should look like:
$$f\left(x\right)=10x+8\mod 13.$$ 
As you can see $a_0$ coefficient here is $8$ so that your guess is right (since $a_0$ is the secret itself).

Comment: n0unc3 did say it saw a (2,3) system; that means that 2 shares were sufficient to recover the secret.  Hence, it's not at all surprising that one of the shares are superfluous...

Comment: @poncho, that's right, thank you. I have removed needless caveat.